# AndEngine with Google Play game services

Tags: android, andengine, google-play-games, andengine-gles-2

Im using AndEngine-GLES2-AnchorCenter and I want implement Google Play game services.

I copied `BaseGameActivity` and `GameHelper` classes from `BaseGameUtils` (part of Google Play game services - Android Samples) to my project in same `util` package.

Because AndEngine already use `BaseGameActivity`, I renamed it to `GBaseGameActivity` and changed extended class to BaseGameActivity (AndEngine class), so from this:

```
public abstract class BaseGameActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

to:

```
public abstract class GBaseGameActivity extends BaseGameActivity
```

Then I extended my class on `GBaseGameActivity` (when I extend BaseGameActivity(AndEngine class), its working ... but not with GBaseGameActivity(BaseGameUtils class) )

```
public class BaseActivity extends GBaseGameActivity
```

I tried compiled my project, but i got:

```
...
Could not find class 'com.xxx.xxx.util.GameHelper', referenced from method com.xxx.xxx.util.GBaseGameActivity.<init>
Could not find class 'com.xxx.xxx.util.GameHelper', referenced from method com.xxx.xxx.util.GBaseGameActivity.onCreate
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.xxx.xxx.util.GameHelper
    at com.xxx.xxx.util.GBaseGameActivity.<init>(GBaseGameActivity.java:63)
    at com.xxx.xxx.BaseActivity.<init>(BaseActivity.java:35)
...
```

GBaseGameActivity.java:63:

```
63| mHelper = new GameHelper(this);
```

BaseActivity.java:35:

```
35| public class BaseActivity extends GBaseGameActivity
```

Where is problem?

Comment: Do you need to change the manifest file?
([see here for example][1])


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822493/android-couldnt-find-class

Comment: I have just 1 activity (`BaseActivity`) extended on `GBaseGameActivity` and `GBaseGameActivity` implements `GameHelper`, so I dont need register it to AndroidManifest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was that `google-play-services` module scope was set to `Provided` instead of `Compile`.