# Google play services (Leaderboards) with AndEngine

Tags: android, android-intent, andengine, google-play-services

I'm trying to integrate Google Play Services into my Andengine Game. Everything is working perfectly and my Leaderboard loads up however my problem is when returning to the game. 
When I go back from Leaderboard to my game, onResume is called my default. When onResume is called my game doen't crash it gives this error:

```
    E/Adreno200-ES20﹕ <qgl2DrvAPI_glUseProgram:1319>: GL_INVALID_VALUE
```

and the screen goes black. 
I have done the changing classes stuff like decribed here:
 [AndEngine with Google Play game services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199072/andengine-with-google-play-game-services)
and here:
[Issues in integrating Google Play Game Services Leaderboard in AndEngine Game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22686201/issues-in-integrating-google-play-game-services-leaderboard-in-andengine-game)

I read somewhere about Overriding OnBackPressed, but I dont know how I can implement this as I have to call startActivityForResult(Intent,string) - where the intent is complied called from google.
However I read in android API that onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) gets called when exiting the Leaderboard activity. my returned values are:

```
  I/requestCode﹕ 1337
  I/resultCode﹕ 0
  I/Intent﹕ null
```

when these are clearly incorrect values, any pointers on the issue would be great.